# Python, Pandas -- How to search for rows based on condition multiple columns above certain value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with 77 columns. Of these, 24 are data indicating percentages.

I know, if I am interested in one column, I can do

```
data[data.iloc[:,53] > 30]
```

And this will return all rows with that column greater than 30. To extend this to multiple columns, the only way I know how is roughly

```
data[(data.iloc[:,53] > 30) & (data.iloc[:,65] > 30)]
```

and so on, for each column.

But I want to

1. Count the number of columns greater than 30%
2. Return only rows with a count greater than 3.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: do you have a typo for your second query? you put `53` both times

Comment: `df[df.gt(30).sum(1)>=3]`

Comment: ```df[(df.iloc[:,53:]>30).sum(1)>3]```

Comment: @aws_apprentice yup. Thanks, corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select rows based on condition above a set of different columns.

Let `l` be the list of index of columns over which you want to apply a condition.

You can directly use  `data.iloc[:,l]` to select the wanted columns.

In your case it gives:

```
l = [53, 65]
data[(data.iloc[:,l]>30).sum(1)>3]
```